# Azure- AD, DC, ADFS

Tags: azure

Can active directory services (Azure) replace my current ADFS servers? I have one on site and another in a DMZ.

Second, Do I need/does it make sense to have a DC on the Azure platform if we have ADFS out there or ist one in the same if we end up using ADFS on Azure?

If we do need a DC, how will it fit in with our distributed DC environment. Performance, geographic dispersion etc---any info on radius server?

How do we migrate- what is the process of migrating our current ADFS platform to Azure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I did some research but Microsoft advised I can't do any of the following but can't provide any reason or supporting docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be entirely helpful but here is good list of ADFS resources - http://simon-may.com/adfs-dirsync-waad-resources/

In many cases, organizations are using ADFS because they have a requirement to authenticate to cloud services using an "on-prem" domain controller (or a DC entirely under their control).

Azure AD can handle all cloud related authentication and sync with local DCs, but Azure AD would be using the cloud-based directory and on-prem authentications would happen with your DCs.

You can run DCs and ADFS servers on Azure VMs and treat those DCs as being located in a different "site" (under AD Sites & Services) to manage replication much like you would do with multiple business locations.

This post is dated, but might be a good start for migration ideas - http://www.concurrency.com/infrastructure/migrate-adfs-for-office-365-to-windows-azure/

If you are using ADFS to meet a B2B need - that is currently in preview for Azure - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/